# Python unittest.mock @Patch behavior when changing `import X` to `from X import`

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have the following client class:

```
import requests

class MyClient:
    def stuff(self):
        req = requests.head("my_url")
        some_bool = check_requests(req) #true if proper response from requests.head
        return some_bool
```

I am testing this client class using the following test:

```
import requests
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch

@patch('requests.head')
def test_myclient_stuff(mock_head):
    my_client = MyClient()
    response = mock_resp()
    mock_head.return_value = response
    my_client.stuff()
    mock_head.assert_called_with("my_url")

def mock_resp():
    response = MagicMock(spec=requests.Response)
    response.status_code = 200
    response.request = MagicMock(spec=requests.PreparedRequest)
    response.headers = {}
    return response
```

All of the above is working correctly and as expected.  However, I am shuffling some of the imports around to the Client as follows:

```
from requests import head

class MyClient:
    def stuff(self):
        req = head("my_url")
        some_bool = check_requests(req) #true if proper response from requests.head
        return some_bool
```

I have tried adjusting the test to use either `@patch('requests.head')` or `from request import head` with `@patch('head')` and neither work.  `@patch('head')` is invalid because it is not a correct reference to `requests.head`.  With `@patch('requests.head')`, it is not actually mocking and trying to connect to actually connect to "my_url".  How do I adjust the test to work with `from requests import head` as opposed to `import requests` and using `requests.head`

Comment: With the code in your last sample, you'd need to `@patch('module_xyz.head')` (replacing 'module_xyz' with the name of the module where you define `MyClient`). The 'from...' style import means that when `MyClient` refers to `head`, `head` is a name in module_xyz's namespace. So that namespace is where you patch it.